# understanding local variables, closures and iterators

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, iterator, closures

I have a code block like the below, it's a sync function.
I want to collect in `reply` info on items.

However reply is always returning as the empty array even when I have items.
When I check in the debugger, the info shows `reply` as a closure variable, not a `local`.
I'm wondering if there's something going on with hoisting here that I don't understand?

[image]

```
  invStatus() {
    let reply: string[] = []
    Logger.log('player.status.items:', this.items)
    if (!this.items.length) {
      reply.push('nothing')
    } else this.items.map(item => {
      Logger.log('item', item)
      reply.push[`- ${item.name}`]
    })
    Logger.log('player.status.reply:', reply)
    return reply
  }
```

hmm this is typescript also, I wonder if the transpiler behavior is subtly different?

I probably should use a `.forEach` here since I'm not capturing the return of the map or transforming things but I understand that has the same iterator behavior. The only other thing would be to go with a `for x of` which is more reliable, but I'd like to understand the issue here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made a syntax error.

Observe this line:

```js
reply.push[`- ${item.name}`]
```

Here, instead of **parantheses**, you have used **square brackets**.

Corrected code would be,

```js
reply.push(`- ${item.name}`)
```

I know javascript but not typescript but I believe this must be the cause of the issue.

Comment: you're right! I use typescript to help prevent me making idiot mistakes like that. Thanks!